# R imputation for strings in selected columns of large dataset

Tags: r, imputation, r-mice

I am struggling with multiple data-imputation packages in R and need your advice.

I have a data-set with 150.000 rows and 270 columns.

Every column has some missing data, but i need to make imputation only in 7 of them. I need all the columns to be considered during the filling of those 7 columns. No numerical data, only strings.

I have tried to use MICE, but it takes too long and do not gives any result because of the break. I believe I am coding it completely wrong.

```
A                  |  B          |  C           |  D        |  E       | 
------------------------------------------------------------------------
DEEP DIGGING ALL   |  1989       |  Digging     |  Sumer    |  Cups    |
SURFACE DIGGING    |  1989       |  N/A         |  Sumer    |  Glasses |
CLAIMS OFFSHORE    |  1990       |  N/A         |  Assyria  |  N/A     | 
OFFSHORE CLAIMS    |  1990       |  Offshore    |  Assyria  |  N/A     |  
CLAIMS OFFSHORE    |  1990       |  Offshore    |  Assyria  |  Cups    |
OFFSHORE CLAIMS    |  1990       |  Offshore    |  Assyria  |  Cups    |
```

What I am trying to get is the table, where the column "C" is imputed based on all of the columns, but N/As in column "E" are ignored.

Desirable result:

```
A                  |  B          |  C           |  D        |  E       | 
------------------------------------------------------------------------
DEEP DIGGING ALL   |  1989       |  Digging     |  Sumer    |  Cups    |
SURFACE DIGGING    |  1989       |  Digging     |  Sumer    |  Glasses |
CLAIMS OFFSHORE    |  1990       |  Offshore    |  Assyria  |  N/A     | 
OFFSHORE CLAIMS    |  1990       |  Offshore    |  Assyria  |  N/A     |  
CLAIMS ONSHORE     |  1990       |  Offshore    |  Assyria  |  Cups    |
OFFSHORE CLAIMS    |  1990       |  Offshore    |  Assyria  |  Cups    |
```

I'm not sure if the "MICE" is the good path to take, but I did not get anywhere with my attempts in "missForest". So I really depend on your help.

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Why would Claims Onshore have column C set to Offshore?

Comment: Sorry for that, It was the random data manipulations, I will edit right now

Comment: I don't think MICE will solve this for you. Multiple imputation is a stochastic process while your problem seems to be deterministic. Since C is directly based on the input in A wouldn't is be better to do something like `df1$C <- ifelse(!is.na(C),C,ifelse(grepl(A,"OFFSHORE"),"Offshore","Digging"))`? This keeps C unchanged if it is not missing, and changes it to "Offshore" if A contains the term "offshore" (or "Digging" if A does not contain the term "offshore")

Answer (score 1):

We can use `fill` from `tidyr`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df1 %>%
   group_by(B) %>%
   fill(C, .direction = 'updown')
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! 
It actually helped, but did not covered everything, that's why I need to implement some AI packs